# Sometimes only some data lose, calling a javascript function but not calling a php function, from the same javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have a code like:

```
function doSomething(customer)
{

var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();

var customer1 = customer;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     document.getElementById("txtSomething").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

var params = "customer=" + customer;

xmlhttp.open("POST","/something.php", true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.send(params);

post.call(this, customer1);

}
```

In some executions, the second function called **post** lose the value on the variable **customer1**, but it arrives well to **something.php**.
Is there something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous. You fire off the AJAX call, but that .`send()` returns **IMMEDIATELY**, without waiting for a response. So your code continues on and does that `post.call()` call, without waiting for anything from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **jQuery Ajax**, where you can setup some callbacks to check the response?

And, it is even more cross-browser than your code probably is! :)

You can do some cool stuff just with this. Check an example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

[Check here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)